# Cross browser login validation using testNG and selenium using testNG.xml

Tags: selenium, automation, testng

I am trying to run tests in parallel with testNG

However, as soon as i start running my tests, my login credentials are entered randomly, either twice in a single browser window, sometimes username is entered in one browser's window and password is entered in another browser's window.

I changed the thread count as well as changed `parallel ="test"` to `parallel="classes"`,`parallel="instances"`,`parallel="methods"`, but my tests are still executed one after another.

Any idea what is the problem here ?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite guice-stage="DEVELOPMENT" name="Test suite" thread-count="2" parallel="tests">
      <test verbose="2" name="ChromeTest">
      <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
        <classes>
          <class name="Wigzo.Automation.DashboardTest"/>
        </classes>
      </test> <!-- Default test -->
    <test verbose="2" name="FirefoxTest">
      <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox" />
        <classes>
          <class name="Wigzo.Automation.DashboardTest"/>
        </classes>
      </test> 
    </suite>
code:-
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
public class DashboardTest {
    WebDriver driver;

  @BeforeTest
  @Parameters("browser")

  public void setup(String browser) throws Exception{

      //Check if parameter passed from TestNG is 'firefox'

      if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){

      //create firefox instance

          driver = new FirefoxDriver();

      }

      //Check if parameter passed as 'chrome'

      else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){

          //set path to chromedriver.exe You may need to download it from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Configuration_files\\chromedriver.exe");

          //create chrome instance

          driver = new ChromeDriver();

      }

     else{

          //If no browser passed throw exception

          throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");

      }

        driver.navigate().to("https://www.gmail.com");
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Page_objectsTest login = new Page_objectsTest(driver);
        Data_source db= new Data_source("Test_data\\Test_data.xls");
         }

  //Function to perform validations
    @Test(priority=0)
     public void valid_login() throws InterruptedException{
     Page_objectsTest.login_method(Data_source.ReadCell("Username",3),Data_source.ReadCell("Password", 3));
     Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

Comment: Can you the login script ?

Comment: Can you also please show us the test code. I am guessing that you are perhaps experiencing a race condition in your code.

Comment: Code added@Krishnan Mahadevan